# How to counter duplicate entry in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, api

Here I am facing an issue of duplicate entries in my database. I have setup a unique patient ID in my controller and I want to add users having the same e-mail, but a unique phone number.

What I have done and tried in my controller function:

```
public function store(Request $request) {    
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'phone'=>'required|min:11|numeric|unique:patients',
        'birth_date' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return $errors->toJson();
    } else {
        $fileNameToStore = 'defaultimg/avatar.png';
        $post = new patient;
        $post->name = $request->input('name');
        $post->email = $request->input('email');
        $post->picture = $fileNameToStore;
        $post->birth_date = $request->input('birth_date');
        $post->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $address = htmlspecialchars($request->input('address'));
        $post->address = $address;
        $post->patient_id = 'PID' . rand(999, 9999999999999);
        $post->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $post->save();

        return response(array(
            'error' => false,
            'message' => 'Patient added successfully', 'patientid' => $post->patient_id,), 200);
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine as per my requirement, but the code throws the following exception:

> QueryException SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'front@gmail.com' for key 'patients_email_unique'

Here is my migration for the `patients` table:

```
Schema::create('patients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('birth_date');
    $table->string('gender');
    $table->string('address');
    $table->string('patient_id');
    $table->string('picture');
    $table->string('phone')->unique();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: show us your user migrations

Comment: thanks for reply sohel you mean patient_table migration ?

Comment: Yes, i mean the table migration you are using for patient model

Comment: U just submit the same email to more than one patients. But you set `unique()` in migration.

Comment: @JagdishSharma you are making email field unique, see my answer, you may have some idea

Comment: thanks for your reply sand of vega i got your point

Comment: thanks to all sohel,sand of vega ,dominik for your valuable time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
$table->string('email')->unique();
```

To

```
$table->string('email');
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use laravel validation for checking a unique in a specific table.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:patients,email',
    'phone'=>'required|min:11|numeric|unique:patients',
    'birth_date' => 'required',
    'gender' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply adnan Mumtaz now my issue is resolved

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't enough. If you have two requests very close together, they can both pass validation, but then the second one will fail because of a duplicate key error. You also need to be ready to catch that exception when you create the record afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the `unique` validation rule to the `email` field like so:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique',
    'phone'=>'required|min:11|numeric|unique:patients',
    'birth_date' => 'required',
    'gender' => 'required',
    'address' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply dominik but i don't want unique email for patient i have setup a unique id already.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->validate($request,[
 'email' => 'required|email|unique',
]);
```

in your migration

```
$table->string('email')->unique();
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply kuldeep mishra my issue is resolved

Answer (score 1):

Use this code. Here the output shows `true` if the data is already found in the database

```
public function alreadyExistEmail(Request $request) {
        $patients = DB::table('patients')
        ->where('email',$request->email)
        ->first();

        if($patients === null )
            return response()->json('false', 200);
        else
            return response()->json('true', 200);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your code king my issue is resolved